# write a function that returns an array of all the values of all the keys it corresponds to

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

I want to create one function that can be called to return an array containing all the values of each object. 
`e.g. function find ("firstName") 
returns ["Virginia", "Zadie", "Jane", "Bell"]`

An explanation would be great too, as I'm incredibly new to programming and trying to learn. Thank you

```
var writers = [
  {
    firstName: "Virginia",
    lastName: "Woolf",
    occupation: "writer",
    age: 59,
    alive: false
  },
  {
    firstName: "Zadie",
    lastName: "Smith",
    occupation: "writer",
    age: 41,
    alive: true
  },
  {
    firstName: "Jane",
    lastName: "Austen",
    occupation: "writer",
    age: 41,
    alive: false
  },
  {
    firstName: "bell",
    lastName: "hooks",
    occupation: "writer",
    age: 64,
    alive: true
  },
];
```

Comment: Please explain what you have tried so far including code examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can create this function using `map()` method.

```js
var writers = [ { firstName: "Virginia", lastName: "Woolf", occupation: "writer", age: 59, alive: false }, { firstName: "Zadie", lastName: "Smith", occupation: "writer", age: 41, alive: true }, { firstName: "Jane", lastName: "Austen", occupation: "writer", age: 41, alive: false }, { firstName: "bell", lastName: "hooks", occupation: "writer", age: 64, alive: true }];

function get(key, arr) {
  return arr.map(function(e) {
    return e[key]
  })
}

console.log(get('firstName', writers))
console.log(get('occupation', writers))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the key as parameter of your find function.

The [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors), used here is in bracket notation.

```
keys= 'name';
variable[key]
```

this is identical to the same, written as dot notation

```
variable.name
```

```js
function find (key) {
    return writers.map(function (a) { 
        return a[key];
    });
}

var writers = [ { firstName: "Virginia", lastName: "Woolf", occupation: "writer", age: 59, alive: false }, { firstName: "Zadie", lastName: "Smith", occupation: "writer", age: 41, alive: true }, { firstName: "Jane", lastName: "Austen", occupation: "writer", age: 41, alive: false }, { firstName: "bell", lastName: "hooks", occupation: "writer", age: 64, alive: true }, ];
               
console.log(find('firstName'));
console.log(find('lastName'));
```